# jQuery not affecting elements after ajax call

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I'm using buddypress with wordpress. I'm using some jQuery and some buttons to show/hide certain table rows based on their classes. When a paginate button is pressed (ie page 2, or page 3 etc) buddypress uses ajax to populate the next page of rows of users.

I'm trying to run my hiding code after this ajax has completed to keep the things hidden that I want.

```
function keepCatOnPaginate () {
    $ = jQuery;

    $('.pagination-links a').click(function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log('ajax stopped, hiding stuff');
                var id = $('#buddypress .nav-tabs li.active a').attr('id');
                console.log('#members-list tbody tr.'+id);
                console.log($('#members-list tbody tr.'+id));
                console.log($('#members-list tbody tr').not('.'+id));
                $('#members-list tbody tr.'+id).show();
                $('#members-list tbody tr').not('.'+id).hide();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Everything seems to work, the console logs happen in the right times. I get a list of jQuery elements for the two last console logs, exactly as I would expect. However the last 2 calls to actually .show() and .hide() just don't do anything. No elements are hidden or shown. Even if I change the .hide() or .show() to something like .css('background','red'), still nothing happens.

If I copy and paste the output of console.log('#members-list tbody tr.'+id); as the selector for .hide() or .show() or anything else, these elements don't seem to get effected.

I cannot see what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Far too little explanation for what you're trying to do or the context in which this runs.  We need to know is this part of an ajax operation?  Are you dynamically loading content?  Why is there a `$(document).ready()` inside an `.ajaxStop()` handler?

Comment: That was just a hail mary pass at the end there. I had no idea why my code wasn't working, and was thinking that perhaps the dom was not loaded and wrapping in document ready might help. I dunno, kinda retarded, but I thought I'd try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ajaxStop()` does not account for the code which fires in the `success` callback. So while the ajax request itself is finished, the code which is injecting new content into the DOM is still running and thus the `hide()` and `show()` calls run before the new content is injected.

Put something to check whether there is new content yet, or wrap the `hide` and `show` methods in a `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess because you've left out the more important parts of what you're doing (there's no ajax call shown here, no dynamically loaded content shown here and no HTML shown).

But, I'm going to guess that you're doing an ajax call and then trying to dynamically load some content and after that content is loaded, you want to hide/show some things.

If that's the case, then you should probably put this code at the end of the the success handler for your ajax call, not in a `.ajaxStop()` handler and certainly not in a `$(document).ready()` handler.

To help you further, we need to see the markup you're targeting and the ajax call that's involved and understand whether you're dynamically inserting any HTML.

Also, you might explain what you're trying to do with this code.  Are you trying to fetch an id value and then use it as a class name?

If there's no ajax involved here at all and you're just handling a click on a tab, then your code should probably just look like this:

```
$('.pagination-links a').click(function() {
    // get active id
    var id = $('#buddypress .nav-tabs li.active a').attr('id');
    // hide all except the one who's class matches the active id
    $('#members-list tbody tr').hide().filter('.' + id).show();
});
```

Comment: I put in plenty of context, told you where the ajax was coming from, and that my code should be running every time after this ajax call finishes. Perhaps re-read my question.

Comment: @NickM - Why aren't you using the success handler for the ajax call?  Definitely remove the `$(document).ready()` part.

Comment: It is buddypress which is handling the pagination and the ajax call, and I'd prefer to not edit its core files. Yep, I've removed the ready call. Figured it out though, see my answer. 

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no function as such to add this for dynamic . Only way is to , add the css rules dynamically into the body/create a new stylsheet .

Ex:

```
$("<style>").text("#newId { width:20px; height:30px; }").appendTo("head");
```